# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I don't know why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, exc-bad-access

I've had my share of this error, and have usually been able to fix it, but this one's got me stumped:

```
self.companyTheme = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CompanyTheme" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

The path is definitely valid; I've separated it into it's own variable and put a breakpoint on it to check.

I get that it means I'm trying to access some memory that can't access, but where?
Any help would be most appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: is `self` valid? in other words, does this code appear in a method that might be getting accidentally called after a dealloc?

Comment: Almost all of the time this means you have (auto)released some variable which you are using in this line. I think we will need more info to help you out :)

Comment: This is a singleton object and the above method gets called right after the good ol' self = [super init]. I also 100% don't autorelease this object (or the variable).

Comment: When you say "This is a singleton" are you talking about the main bundle?(which is obvious) or self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out!

It was because my object was a singleton and I had an infinite loop going in my app. I didn't know these also caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The things you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Id' bet that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CompanyTheme" ofType:@"plist"]]` returns `nil` and `initWithContentsOfFile:` doesn't handle a nil argument well at all and crashes when `nil` translates the the memory address `0x0`.

Comment: The path is definitely valid; I've separated it into it's own variable and put a breakpoint on it to check.

Comment: @Dyldo42: Keep separating out. What does `-pathForResource:ofType:` return? Make sure that that is ALSO non-nil. The simplest way to debug this compound statement is to break out every single individual operation. This takes just a few moments and will significantly narrow down the culprit area.

Comment: I have done that. I said that in the original question and in the comment above. The path is '/var/mobile/Applications/BE39E65E-7584-4C36-B3C4-37CBD5B6660B/App.app/CompanyTheme.plist' and this is returned from pathForResource:ofType:

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a very specific error. Generally when something won’t accept a nil value, it throws an NSInvalidArgumentException. The problem is something else.